# Jquery запрос  $.ajax. Все время возникает ошибка.

Tags: jquery, ajax

Приветствую.
Что-то я уже голову совсем сломал. Дело следующем:
Подключены:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.json-2.4.js"></script>
```

Функция на JS:

```
function CopySelectedWork()  
{  
//Выдергиваем все отмеченные элементы  
var ArrayCheckedID = [];  
var CheckedWork = $('#WorksTable input[name="WorksArray"]:checked');  
var i;  
    for (i=0; i<CheckedWork.length; i++)   
            {  
            ArrayCheckedID[i] = (CheckedWork[i].id);  
            }  
$.ajax({ // отправляем данные   
            url:"test.php"  
            , cache: false  
            , timeout: 10000  
            , type:'POST'  
            , datatype: "json"  
                        , data:'jsonData=' + $.toJSON(ArrayCheckedID)  
            , success: function(res)   
            {alert(res);}  
            , error: function(jqXHR, exception) {  
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {  
                alert('.');  
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {  
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');  
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {  
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');  
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {  
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');  
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {  
                alert('Time out error.');  
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {  
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');  
            } else {  
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);  
            }  
            }  
            });  
 return false;  
}
```

</code>

test.php прост до безобразия:

```
<?php  
$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);  
$response = 'Получено параметров '.count($data).'\n';  
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) 
{  
    $response .= 'Параметр: '.$key.'; Значение: '.$value.'\n';  
}  
echo $response;
```

?>

при отправке ошибка: Not connect. Verify Network. т.е. jqXHR.status = 0
причем ошибка возникает в любом случае. Подскажите где не прав.

Comment: @gus_ak, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: > `datatype: "json", `

то что вы присылаете в ответ не является json, вот оно и ругается.

Comment: с jquery-1.3.1.min.j и jquery.json-1.3.js работает.
только мне нужна jquery-1.8.3.js

Comment: с тех пор как была 1.3 прошло много лет, или уберите datatype, или возвращайте json из php.

Comment: убирал, не помогает:(

Comment: а локальный сервер с РНР работает?

Comment: да. конечно. только он не локальный:) причем если написать код php который нужен, он у меня создает дубликаты выбранный записей в БД mysql, то все отрабатывает.

Comment: Ну тогда посмотрите, куда javascript посылает запрос. Может адрес не верный каким-то образом.

Comment: все отсылается куда нужно. и php отрабатывает. но почему-то все время возникает ошибка. и отрабатывает ф-я error.
[вот тут][1]
  [1]: http://www.simplecoding.org/otpravka-dannyx-v-formate-json-s-pomoshhyu-javascript-i-jquery.html
реальный пример который который у меня работает. но с jquery1.3

Comment: Ну тогда нужно поправить только одну строчку:

      data: {'jsonData' : JSON.stringify(ArrayCheckedID)},

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте

```
processData: false
```

и уберите

```
timeout
```